# Dynamic DLL and ESP corruption

Tags: winapi, dll

I'm learning to use dynamic DLL. I have created 2 functions i DLL library:

```
DWORD fn1(VOID);
DWORD fn2(WCHAR*);
```

and exported it using def file

```
EXPORTS
fn1
fn2
```

When I load&use fn1, everything is ok, but the second is causing problem `Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`

pointers are defined like:

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *fn1)(void);
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *fn2)( WCHAR* );
```

and loaded like this:

```
fn1 first = NULL;
fn2 second = NULL;
first = (fn1) GetProcAddress( dll,  "fn1" ); 
second = (fn2) GetProcAddress( dll,  "fn2" );
```

Can you help me, what could cause the problem - when I "continue" application works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the declaration of the function pointer type is not correct.  It doesn't match in your snippet either, you declared them WINAPI.  Which is a macro that sets their calling convention to __stdcall.  You however didn't declare the actual functions with the same attribute.  The default is __cdecl.

You got away with it for `fn1` because it doesn't have any arguments so getting the calling convention wrong doesn't imbalance the stack.  It does for `fn2`.  The generated code doesn't pop the passed argument off the stack after the function call as required by __cdecl.

Remove WINAPI to fix.